# flatron w1934s screen can't be detected ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, multiple-monitors, display

I using Ubuntu 22.04 and when connecting flatron w1934s LG screen, Ubuntu can not detect it.
I tried the screen on a windows machine and the screen is working fine.

I used the latest version of the Nvidia drivers

This is the output of xrandr

Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
XWAYLAND0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 190mm
1920x1080    119.93*+
1440x1080    119.92
1400x1050    119.90
1280x1024    119.96
1280x960     119.89
1152x864     119.77
1024x768     119.80
800x600      119.85
640x480      119.52
320x240      117.34
1680x1050    119.89
1440x900     119.94
1280x800     119.85
720x480      119.65
640x400      119.64
320x200      117.55
1600x900     119.95
1368x768     119.83
1280x720     119.86
1024x576     119.85
864x486      119.69
720x400      119.54
640x350      119.24

Comment: Is it the right driver for the unknown model of the video card? You have tagged multi monitor but the question has nothing about multi monitors.

Comment: I am using the Nvidia driver the one labled 'tested'